# s3_swf_upload fails regularly while uploading files to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I've been having this issue for sometime now. On fillim.com (indie film distribution, so large files) we're using using [this fork](https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin) of the `s3_swf_upload` gem for rails. We're getting everyone complaining that it will fail sometimes 3-4 times before it will fully upload the file, like almost everyone.

We're on Heroku, and we're then of course needing to do direct uploads to S3.

We're not getting any errors generated, in our logs or in the browser, and we just can not for the life of us find the cause.

Has anyone had these issues before? Does anyone know of alternatives? If anyone knows of an alternative that supports files larger than 2GB, that would be even better.

Comment: I've updated this guys, I obviously wasn't clear with the fact we're doing direct uploads from the flash uploader to S3.

Answer (score 0):

If You are trying to upload files on amazon s3, Then use AWS::S3 a Ruby Library for uploading files.

http://amazon.rubyforge.org/

Comment: AWS::S3  allows user to upload files to s3 or download files from s3 using AWS::S3::S3Object.

Answer (score 0):

I thing default size

```
:fileSizeLimit (integer = 524288000)
Individual file size limit in bytes (default is 512 MB)
```

you need to increase your filesizelimit

Answer (score 0):

The repeated failures is unsurprising. If you're going to upload files that large, you want to leverage S3's "multipart upload" support. Essentially, the file is broken-up into pieces, sent in parts, then reassembled on the S3-side.

The official [AWS SDK for Ruby](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/MultipartUpload.html) supports this feature, but you'd have to implement it into your gem. I don't know whether or not that's outside the scope of what you were looking for.

Also, am I correct in understanding that you're wanting to allow users to upload files > 2GB from their *web browsers*?